# Mixed versions warning when using android support renderscript api

Tags: android, android-support-library, renderscript

I'm using support renderscript and android support library 25.1.0, I'm getting this warning in my module build.gradle :

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.1.0, 25.0.2. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.1.0 and com.android.support:renderscript:25.0.2

Here is my code to get the renderscript support library :

```
android{
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
       ...
       targetSdkVersion 25
       versionCode Integer.valueOf(versionId)
       versionName version
       renderscriptTargetApi 20
       renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
       multiDexEnabled true
       minSdkVersion minSdk
 }
}
```

It seems that the support renderscript version is linked with the build-tools one...
How can I fix this without using a lower android support library version ?

Comment: This topic has already been discussed here.
Here's the help you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655867/5389995

Comment: Thanks @BrandonZamudio, I've seen this topic already but the thing is I cannot just add `com.android.support:renderscript:25.1.0`, because renderscript should be added in the default config block `renderscriptTargetApi 20 renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug that is fixed in up-coming Android Studio 2.4 release.

It also safe to ignore the warnings for RenderScript support lib, if you keep using Android Studio 2.3. The warnings are incorrect, and won't affect your app.

Comment: For reference this is the issue's link:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37630182